# Count active sessions

Tags: php, session, memcached

I store my sessions with memcached. I am looking to detect how many active sessions there are currently.

I am convinced it must be possible - But I have googled and googled but to no avail so please stackoverflowers give me some guidence :)

Comment: I could see it being useful if you wanted to display how many sessions are currently active etc.

Comment: I want to limit the number of users that can use my application at one time... in order to do so I must know how many users are currently using it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached by nature isn't meant to be used like that (it's a fleeting cache store, it is not intended to do SQL  / database like aggregate queries over), and current active sessions is usually not something I am remotely interested in (for load purposes, the hits & statistical data of the webserver is much more to the point).

If you are however use memcache *only* to store session-data (not other key-value pairs), you can use [`getStats()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.getstats.php) to get an item count (`cur_items`) on the current memcache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_session_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to save your sessions to a database, then getting active sessions is as easy as querying the database.