# Count numbers of active sessions

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Number of Open Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679657/find-number-of-open-sessions)
>   [Access active sessions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php)

When a user arrives to a webpage, a session variable is created for the user and I wonder if it's possible to count the numbers of active sessions?

Comment: Active Sessions all together by all users on the website?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Find Number of Open Sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679657/find-number-of-open-sessions), [Access active sessions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php), and [Looping Through All a Server's Sessions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675913/looping-through-all-a-servers-sessions-in-php)

Comment: Using the default session handler? `sess_*` files under `session.save_path`?

Comment: Another related, possible duplicate: [Count active sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4071764/367456)

Comment: AFAIK PHP doesn't keep an index of sessions, active or otherwise. What storage mechanism are you using?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: If this is really a "must have" feature for your app, investigate custom session handling, it will make it far easier to do things like identifying which users have more than 1 session etc. (I think it was deviantart that tells me that I have sessions open from specific browser/OS/IP or something)

Comment: I'd say as well, custom session handler will help you there. Running stats while saving sessions. Also put a timestamp into the session data and save it along with the bucket. Writing sessions handlers has become more easy btw.

Comment: OK, it's not a "must have" I was just interested to make some code to check how many active user a webpage have

Answer (score 3):

> When a user arrives to a webpage, a session variable is created for the user and I wonder if it's possible to count the numbers of active sessions?

Everything you store something can be counted. However, by default, values in a sessions are per user, PHP does not track all sessions all together or something.

So it's up to you to create that context. For example, you can write your own session handler.

That got much easier with PHP 5.4 because you can now extend the standard session handler and just add the functionality you need. Please see the manual page: [The SessionHandler class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php)

So how could this work? Each time the session is there, you write into a datastore that is *shared* that there is an active session. If the session get's destroyed, e.g. by garbage collection or because you compare against the time and enough time has passed since the last activity, you then can count that via the shared datastore.

Comment: If you just want experiment a bit, there is an example session file viewer in a library called Serialized, that might be interesting for you when you just want to play around apart from the session handler itself: https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/blob/master/examples/03-session/example-viewer.php

Comment: This is an excellent use case for using database for sessions. Then you can literally just count the number of records that represent active sessions.

Comment: @ConcordusApplications: Yes, you can give it a timestamp column for example. However, for sessions, consider some storage that is faster, e.g. memory: [Not only SQL - memcache and MySQL 5.6](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/152-Not-only-SQL-memcache-and-MySQL-5.6.html)

Comment: @hakre...I totally agree. DB is a slow way to handle sessions, but some type of central segregated storage becomes the only way to do this reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are stored in temp files in the session.save_path (in ini file) folder. Each file begin with "sess_". I think you could count the number of these files to know how many sessions are active.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't have access to a file like that if I'm using a web hotel?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know what you mean by a web hotel? Is it shared hosting?

Comment: @Phenix Apparently some hosting companies brand their hosting as a 'Web Hotel'.. gotta love marketers

Comment: @Mike Thanks, i never heard this term before... but i'm french, your marketers didn't come to us (yet!)

Comment: @3D-kreativ I think you won't have access to such data in a "Web Hotel"

Comment: OK, I guess this idea that I had about counting the numbers of sessions, will just be an idea! Seems to complicated and perhaps not possible to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get the number of sessions with this:

```
$sessionCount = count(glob(session_save_path()."/*"));
```

However, you will need to make sure that session garbage collection is configured correctly so you don't get dead session files in there.

Comment: If session_save_path() is /tmp this has the potential to be wildly incorrect.

Comment: That's assuming you're using the default session storage mechanism(file) and it's not shared with any other PHP application.

Comment: True. I forgot that I usually create a folder specifically for session files...

Comment: @Leigh: Yes, the whole answer makes a bit the impression it's put in a little bit too quickly ;)

Comment: I never use the filesystem for storing sessions anyway. For active user counts I use a redis store...expiring caches exist for a reason

Comment: This approach doesn't work if you are in a shared hosting environment or if you have multiple apps using the same session storage.